# SQL Date Formatting Issue

Tags: sql

I have the following query which works great when I was just looking for data in 2012. Now we're in 2013 and its becoming a bit confusing. I have been trying to do a query where it brings back the results with a date format that would look like: Jan 2012, Feb 2012.... and then also have Jan 2013, Feb 2013. How would I achieve this? Thanks

```
SELECT 
    fp.name                                                  AS [Name],
    YEAR(fp.date)                                            AS [Year],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '1'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [JAN],       
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '2'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [FEB],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '3'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [MAR],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '4'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [APR],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '5'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [MAY],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '6'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [JUN],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '7'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [JUL],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '8'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [AUG],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '9'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [SEP],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '10'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [OCT],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '11'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [NOV],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fp.date) = '12'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [DEC],
    COUNT(*)                                                 AS [Overall]

    FROM f_page_views fp


    WHERE fp.date > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND fp.date < '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'

    GROUP BY 
    year(fp.date)
```

Comment: Are you trying to add fields to the query every year like `[Jan 2012],,,[Jan 2013],...[Dec 2013]`? So if you filter by `2012-01-01` and `2015-12-31` you should have 48 fields?

Comment: Yes, that what I was trying to do :|

Comment: Not sure how your front end (if any) cope with it when you have different number of fields in the result set for different date values. To get such results, you may need to use a `PIVOT`, [here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145694/pivot-with-month).

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT  fp.Name,
        [Jan 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120101' AND fp.Date < '20120201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Feb 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120201' AND fp.Date < '20120301' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Mar 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120301' AND fp.Date < '20120401' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Apr 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120401' AND fp.Date < '20120501' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [May 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120501' AND fp.Date < '20120601' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Jun 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120601' AND fp.Date < '20120701' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Jul 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120701' AND fp.Date < '20120801' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Aug 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120801' AND fp.Date < '20120901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Sep 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20120901' AND fp.Date < '20121001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Oct 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20121001' AND fp.Date < '20121101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Nov 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20121101' AND fp.Date < '20121201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Dec 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20121201' AND fp.Date < '20130101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Jan 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130101' AND fp.Date < '20130201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Feb 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130201' AND fp.Date < '20130301' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Mar 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130301' AND fp.Date < '20130401' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Apr 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130401' AND fp.Date < '20130501' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [May 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130501' AND fp.Date < '20130601' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Jun 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130601' AND fp.Date < '20130701' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Jul 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130701' AND fp.Date < '20130801' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Aug 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130801' AND fp.Date < '20130901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Sep 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20130901' AND fp.Date < '20131001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Oct 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20131001' AND fp.Date < '20131101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Nov 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20131101' AND fp.Date < '20131201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Dec 2013] = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= '20131201' AND fp.Date < '20140101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    f_page_views fp
WHERE   fp.date > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
AND     fp.date < '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY fp.Name;
```

Note, rather than using `WHEN MONTH(fp.Date) = 1 AND YEAR(fp.Date) = 2012` I have used `WHEN fp.Date >= '20120101' AND fp.Date < '20120201'`, although this means the same thing the latter will perform better, especially if you have indexes on `fp.Date`

An alternative would be to use the PIVOT function:

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  fp.Name,
            ViewMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, fp.Date), 0),
            Value = 1
    FROM    f_Page_Views
    WHERE   fp.date > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND     fp.date < '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Data
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(Value)
            FOR ViewMonth IN 
            (   [20120101], [20120201], [20120301], [20120401], [20120501], [20120601],
                [20120701], [20120801], [20120901], [20121001], [20121101], [20121201],
                [20130101], [20130201], [20130301], [20130401], [20130501], [20130601],
                [20130701], [20130801], [20130901], [20131001], [20131101], [20131201]
            ) pvt
```

If you need the columns dynamically created based on a date range supplied then you can use dynamic SQL with either of the methods above:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20120101',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '20131231';


SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ',' + QUOTENAME(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, StartDate), 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, StartDate)) + ' = SUM(CASE WHEN fp.Date >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 112) + ''' AND fp.Date < ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, EndDate, 112) + ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'
FROM    (   SELECT  [StartDate] = DATEADD(MONTH, Number, @StartDate),
                    [EndDate] = DATEADD(MONTH, 1 + Number, @StartDate)
            FROM    Master..spt_values
            WHERE   Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @Enddate)
            AND     Type = 'P'
        ) d

SET @SQL = 'SELECT  fp.Name' + @SQL + ' FROM f_page_views fp WHERE fp.date > @Start AND fp.Date < @End GROUP BY fp.Name';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME', @StartDate, @EndDate;
```

OR

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20120101',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '20131231';

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, Number, @StartDate), 112))
FROM    Master..spt_values
WHERE   Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @Enddate)
AND     Type = 'P';

SET @SQL = 'WITH Data AS
            (   SELECT  fp.Name,
                        ViewMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, fp.Date), 0),
                        Value = 1
                FROM    f_Page_Views fp
                WHERE   fp.date > @Start
                AND     fp.date < @End
            )
            SELECT  *
            FROM    Data
                    PIVOT
                    (   SUM(Value)
                        FOR ViewMonth IN (' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 1, '') + ')
                    ) pvt';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME', @StartDate, @EndDate;
```

Comment: Excellent! thanks so much, this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Note, I assumed SQL-Server was the DBMS based on the use of square brackets in the question.