# Sum within a Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate a field when a condition is met. i've been playing about with this for hours but have had no luck :(.

So I need to find and calculate the Margin for each month. i did this for sales which was a simple

`SUM(CASE when CalendarMonth = 1 then TotalSales else 0 end) as 'January',`

However when trying to calculate the margin i often get the error 
**'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'**

Am i going about this the complete wrong way?

```
    Declare @Sales numeric, @Cost numeric, @Margin Numeric

    Set @Sales = (Select SUM(TotalSales)
            From SalesAnalysis2)

    Set @Cost = (Select SUM(TotalCost)
            From SalesAnalysis2)

    Set @Margin = ((@Sales - @Cost) / @Sales)

    Select distinct

    Case CalendarMonth when 1 then @Margin else 0 end as 'January',
    Case CalendarMonth when 2 then @Margin else 0 end as 'Febuary',
    Case CalendarMonth when 3 then @Margin else 0 end as 'March',
    Case CalendarMonth when 4 then @Margin else 0 end as 'April',
    Case CalendarMonth when 5 then @Margin else 0 end as 'May',
    Case CalendarMonth when 6 then @Margin else 0 end as 'June',
    Case CalendarMonth when 7 then @Margin else 0 end as 'July',
    Case CalendarMonth when 8 then @Margin else 0 end as 'August',
    Case CalendarMonth when 9 then @Margin else 0 end as 'September',
    Case CalendarMonth when 10 then @Margin else 0 end as 'Octocber',
    Case CalendarMonth when 11 then @Margin else 0 end as 'November',
    Case CalendarMonth when 12 then @Margin else 0 end as 'December'

    From SalesAnalysis2

    where CustomerID = 2829 and BranchID = 0 and CalendarYear = Year(Getdate())
```

[image: The code above gives this result but only 0s]

This is the sales one i did, i need to use the same format to display margin.
However there isn't a margin field within the same table, it needs to be calculated
[Sales Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMDh.jpg)

Comment: So you want to display the same Margin value for every month?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the `SUM` with a `CASE` that you've supplied; so I don't think that's the problem. For example, this works fine: `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Object_ID % 2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM sys.tables;` What is the FULL query you've tried?

Comment: Look into using `Pivot` https://stackoverflow.com/a/7146009/468973

Comment: What row is throwing that error.  I am having trouble believing that query throws that error.  Even if it did not error why would you want the same @Margin for each month?

Comment: Hey sorry for my poor explaining, the query I've shown above returns the image attached at the bottom, (all 0s) i've tried playing around with this but often get the error! But yes i need to display Margin for each month

Comment: As you are getting a result row, there must be at least one record matching `where CustomerID = 2829 and BranchID = 0 and CalendarYear = Year(Getdate())` in the table. As you only get zeros, however, there is no record among these with `CalendarMonth between 1 and 12`. So either you have stored other numbers (e.g. 201811 instead of 11) or they are null. You may want to check this with `Select CalendarMonth, count(*) From SalesAnalysis2 where CustomerID = 2829 and BranchID = 0 and CalendarYear = Year(Getdate()) Group By CalendarMonth`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform your margin calculation for each month, rather than using the variable that you've only set once.  In addition, to use the case statement as a pivot you'll also need a MAX aggregate to reduce the number of rows returned.  Otherwise you'll get a row for each month, with only one column in each row having a value other than 0.

```
WITH p AS
  (
    SELECT      CalendarMonth,
                TotalSales = SUM( TotalSales ),
                TotalCost = SUM( TotalCost ),
                Profit = SUM( TotalSales - TotalCost )
      FROM      SalesAnalysis2
      GROUP BY  CalendarMonth
  )
  SELECT
    MAX(CASE CalendarMonth when 1 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'January',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 2 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'Febuary',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 3 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'March',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 4 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'April',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 5 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'May',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 6 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'June',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 7 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'July',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 8 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'August',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 9 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'September',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 10 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'Octocber',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 11 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'November',
    MAX(Case CalendarMonth when 12 then p.Profit/p.TotalSales else 0 END) as 'December'
  FROM    p
```

Since you have not provided any schema or data, you will need to modify this to fit your data.  It may not provide accurate results for your data as written, but it should at least return different values for each month and will hopefully get you closer to the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
Declare @Sales numeric, @Cost numeric, @Margin Numeric

Set @Sales = (Select SUM(TotalSales)
        From SalesAnalysis2)

Set @Cost = (Select SUM(TotalCost)
        From SalesAnalysis2)

Set @Margin = ((@Sales - @Cost) / @Sales)

Select distinct

Case Month(YourDateColumn) =1 then @Margin else 0 end as 'January',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =2 then @Margin else 0 end as 'Febuary',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =3 then @Margin else 0 end as 'March',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =4 then @Margin else 0 end as 'April',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =5 then @Margin else 0 end as 'May',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =6 then @Margin else 0 end as 'June',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =7 then @Margin else 0 end as 'July',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =8 then @Margin else 0 end as 'August',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =9 then @Margin else 0 end as 'September',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =10 then @Margin else 0 end as 'Octocber',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =11 then @Margin else 0 end as 'November',
Case Month(YourDateColumn) =12 then @Margin else 0 end as 'December'

From SalesAnalysis2

where CustomerID = 2829 and BranchID = 0 and CalendarYear = Year(Getdate())
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, i tried this out but it's still only returning 0s

Comment: Can you define your table structure with few data?

Answer (score 0):

You want a `sum()`:

```
Select sum(Case CalendarMonth when 1 then @Margin else 0 end) as January,
       sum(Case CalendarMonth when 2 then @Margin else 0 end) as February,
       . . .
From SalesAnalysis2
where CustomerID = 2829 and BranchID = 0 and
      CalendarYear = Year(Getdate())
```

Comment: Hey, Tried this still returns 0s :(

Comment: @M.tovey . . . Then `CalendarMonth` does not take on the values 1, 2, 3, . . .