# How can I get values of the Rating column together with their definition for every specific month by using Pivot with Month in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

Example :

**Data:**

```
GraphDetails
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| Id  GoalId  Definition                Rating  DateCrated |
| -------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   2       Zero Infra Back Log       100     2020-02-05 |
| 2   2       Happy Customers           95      2020-02-05 |
| 3   2       Complete All Projects     100     2020-02-05 |
| 4   1       Zero Infra Back Log       100     2020-02-05 |
| 5   1       Happy Customers           98      2020-02-05 |
| 6   1       Complete All Projects     100     2020-02-05 |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

***Query:***

```
SELECT
 [1] AS Jan,
 [2] AS Feb,
 [3] AS Mar,
 [4] AS Apr,
 [5] AS May,
 [6] AS Jun,
 [7] AS Jul,
 [8] AS Aug,
 [9] AS Sep,
 [10] AS Oct,
 [11] AS Nov,
 [12] AS [Dec]
FROM
(Select Id, MONTH(DateRecorded) as TMonth
  FROM GraphDetails
    WHERE YEAR(DateRecorded) = 2020 AND GoalId = 1
    ) source
PIVOT
( Definition, Rating
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] ) 
) AS pvtMonth
```

***I get this error:***

Incorrect syntax near ','.

*In line with* " Definition, Rating "

***Result should look like this:***

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Definition              | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Zero Infra Back Log     | 0   | 100 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| Happy Customers         | 0   | 98  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| Complete All Projects   | 0   | 100 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Is this possible? 
Any help, please!

Thank you!

*The code above was based on [PIVOT with MONTH()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145694/pivot-with-month).

Comment: You're trying to `PIVOT` on 2 columns: `PIVOT
( Definition, Rating...`.  The `PIVOT` operator doesn't support more than 1 column. Seems like you'll be better off with a [Cross-Tab](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%E2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    definition,
    sum(case 
        when dateRecorded >= datefromparts(2020, 1, 1) and dateRecorded < datefromparts(2020, 2, 1)
        then rating
        else 0
    end) Jan,
    sum(case 
        when dateRecorded >= datefromparts(2020, 2, 1) and dateRecorded < datefromparts(2020, 3, 1)
        then rating
        else 0
    end) Feb,
    ...
    sum(case 
        when dateRecorded >= datefromparts(2020, 12, 1) and dateRecorded < datefromparts(2021, 1, 1)
        then rating
        else 0
    end) Dec
from graphDetails
where dateRecorded >= datefromparts(2020, 1, 1) and dateRecorded < datefromparts(2021, 1, 1)
group by definition
order by definition
```

This syntax is somehow more flexible than the specific `PIVOT` operator (and also, for what it's worth, it works across different database products).

Note that I modified the filters on dates so it uses half-open intervals, and no date function is applied on column `dateRecorded`: this should allow the database to take advantage of an index on the date column (and would also smoothly handle the time component of `dateCreated`, if any).

Comment: Thank you so much! But why Is it that the only Jan | Feb | Dec of the month appeared. Is it possible to display from Jan until Dec(Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec)?  Thanks!

Comment: @TonithAlbiso: sure. You just need to expand the `select` clause with more conditional expressions. For the sake of brievity, I just demonstrated the solution for Jan, Feb and Dec (there are `...` in between for you to fill).

Comment: Perfect! I got it. It works! I appreciate your help. It took me two weeks to solve this problem and now I got this in just a few mins. Wow!. Thank you so much! @GMB

Comment: @GMB . . . I'm curious why you would use `datefromparts(2020, 1, 1)` instead of `'2020-01-01'` or `'20200101'` (the former is ISO standard and works in most databases, the latter is guaranteed to work in SQL Server).

Answer (score 1):

**Query:**

```
SELECT [Definition], isnull([1],0) AS Jan,
         isnull([2],0) AS Feb,
         isnull([3],0) AS Mar,
         isnull([4],0) AS Apr,
         isnull([5],0) AS May,
         isnull([6],0) AS Jun,
         isnull([7],0) AS Jul,
         isnull([8],0) AS Aug,
         isnull([9],0) AS Sep,
         isnull([10],0) AS Oct,
         isnull([11],0) AS Nov,
         isnull([12],0) AS [Dec]
        FROM
       (Select Id, MONTH(DateCrated) as TMonth,[Definition],Rating
          FROM GraphDetails
       WHERE YEAR(DateCrated) = 2020 AND GoalId = 1
        ) [source]
    PIVOT
    (  
    sum(Rating)
        FOR TMonth 
        IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] ) 
    ) AS pvtMonth
```

[Result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqfYW.png)